# Unable to scroll Gnome app list. How do I fix this?

Tags: gnome, desktop-apps

To reproduce:

1. Press super key to bring up the Gnome app management view. (Is there a name for this?)
2. Click on the 3x3 array of dots in the dock to bring up the app list.
3. Click on the "All" tab at the bottom.

There should now be dots along the right that seem to represent the number of pages of apps. I have three. When clicked they do nothing. Arrow keys and page up/down keys do nothing. Scrolling with the touch pad does nothing.

I can, however, search for (and find, and open) apps that are not shown, so, clearly there should be more pages.
Am I doing something wrong, or is something broken?

Comment: Please specify version of Ubuntu you are using. Have you fully updated your Ubuntu machine? Maybe a buggy GNOME extension is causing this. Can you try with a freshly created Linux user?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I installed Ubuntu on this computer just a couple weeks ago: "Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS". Maybe restoring the home directory could have overwritten something? I used `rsync -avHu`; u syncs updates, so I wouldn't overwrite newer files, but maybe modification dates were old? What file might have been overwritten?

Comment: Yes other users can scroll their app list. @FedonKadifeli

Comment: So indeed a user config issue. Could be a Gnome Shell extension you have, so you could first look into that.

Comment: @vanadium The only enabled plug-ins are the three Built-Ins: "Desktop Icons", "Ubuntu AppIndicators" and "Ubuntu Dock". Disabling "Ubuntu Dock" seems to fix the issue. 